# extract url from xml response and redirect

Tags: php

I'm using curl to post form data in xml string.
The xml response is `<redirect_url>www.xxxxx.com</redirect_url>`.
Could anyone help me to extract this url and redirect the user to it?
Thanks.

Sorry been away...
Thanks for the responses.
The code is:

// create a new cURL resource

```
$ch = curl_init('http://www.zzz.com/');
```

// set r appropriate options

```
$strXML = "<lead>   <applicant>   <title>".$title."</title>   <fname>".$fname."</fname>   <lname>".$lname."</lname>   <email>".$email."</email>   <dob>".$dob."</dob>   </lead>";
```

echo $strXML;

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
```

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, '1');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('lead'=>$strXML));
$strResult = curl_exec($ch);
// close cURL resource, and free up system resources

```
echo $strResult;
```

curl_close($ch);

Example Response:

```
<result>
<posting_error>0</posting_error>
<valid_partner>1</valid_partner>
<redirect_url>www.xxx.com</redirect_url>
</result>
```

Comment: That doesn't look like XML to me. Could you show your code and the full response?

Comment: The website you put as example is actually a nudity website!

Answer (score 5):

Use `SimpleXML` and `header`:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml_response);

header('Location: ' . $xml->redirect_url);
```